# Can Session Timeout and FormAuthentication Timeout make this effect,how will i change it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, global-asax

I have Asp.net website project.I am looking for Active user numbers (Active sessions) using `Global.asax` file;

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    Application["UsersOnline"] = 0;
}
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
}
void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Application.Lock();
    Application["UsersOnline"] = (int)Application["UsersOnline"] -1 ;
    Application.UnLock();
}
```

And this is Login page where i increase Application state when user is log in;

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionstring = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServerTracking"].ConnectionString;
            string sqlstring;
            sqlstring = "Select Name,Password,ID,SessionStateID from Employee where Name=@UserName and Password=@Password";

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlstring, con);

            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserName", Login1.UserName));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Password", Login1.Password));
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader reader;

            // open a connection with sqldatabase
            try
            {
                using (con)
                {
                    con.Open();

                    reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                   Boolean read= reader.Read();
                   online = Convert.ToInt32(reader["SessionStateID"]);
                    if (read)
                    {
                       Session["Name"] = Login1.UserName;
                        Session["Password"] = Login1.Password;
                        Session["ID"] = reader["ID"].ToString();
                        int ID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ID"]);
                        var matches = from p in entities.Employees
                                      where p.ID ==ID
                                      select p;
                        // Execute the query and return the entity object.
                       Employee emp = matches.Single();
                        // Change the entity object.
                        emp.SessionStateID = 0;
                        // Commit the changes back to the database.
                        entities.SaveChanges();
                         Application["UsersOnline"] = (int)Application["UsersOnline"] + 1;
                        e.Authenticated = true;

                    }

                    else {

                            Label1.Text = "User not exist";
                            e.Authenticated = false;
                }
```

Now if i log in **Applications State** increase to 1, After logging out and loggin still 1,if using new tab **log in with same user** or **another user** application State increase to 2.Which works great.However after some time passed i logged in and see negative value like -7 . Only thing i can think of is Session Timeout.If i use Session.Abandon() will Session Timeout still effect after some time? How will i prevent it, shouldnt be case or if there is anything i cant see what can it be?

```
   <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" defaultUrl="userHome.aspx" timeout="60" />
  <sessionState cookieless="true" cookieName="ASP.NET_SessionId" regenerateExpiredSessionId="false" timeout="5" mode="InProc"></sessionState>
```

Comment: Are you using a favorite icon in your website? Is it MS MVC? I found some posts on forums that users complaining about Session_Start being called twice. Some told that happens because they use a `favicon.ico` (weird). Anyway, you should still try to map looged user to check if works.

Comment: No its regular Asp website project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have two different Application variables and increase accordingly:

```
Application["UsersOnline"]
Application["LoggedUsers"]
```

As long you as your logged user logs out and your session is abandoned, you are redirecting this user to another page in your website, right? If so, ASP.NET will likely create another *new* session for this same user and increase `Application["UsersOnline"]`.

You will only see a decrease for expired sessions, people who no longer make requests, posts, in 20 minutes (or other configured values).

If you want to keep track to `Application["LoggedUsers"]`, make sure to increase this number on user login and decrease on logout. Also, make sure that, on `Session_End`, you discover if the session is a logged user. If so, then decrease the `Application["LoggedUsers"]`.

**EDIT**

The complete solution would be something like this.

1. Leave your login event as is.
2. I don't know how you do that, but your logout should look like this:

   ```
    public BtnLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Abandon();
    }
   ```
3. Change your `Session_End` to this:

   ```
    void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
       if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Session["Name"]))
       {
           Application.Lock();
           Application["UsersOnline"] = (int)Application["UsersOnline"] -1 ;
           Application.UnLock();
       }
    }
   ```

When you call `Session.Abandon()`, session is marked to be deleted, but not deleted right away. This means you can perform some cleanup stuff on `Session_End`. That's exactly what we are doing.

We want make sure we are decrementing `Application["UsersOnline"]` for users that were logged in only, not the ones who have a session (it would be literally everyone who calls the website, depending no how you build your pages). This guarantees we are only decrementing users who incremented the variable before.

Comment: @YourSolutionPartner No, the `LoggedUsers` are increased just when users login. You decrement it on logout, but also when sessions expires (not everyone will press logout, just close the browser.. so you will wait until session ends.. so this means decrementing ALSO on `Session_End`).

Comment: @YourSolutionPartner Wonderful! I asked to create these two variables so you could see the difference. Don't forget to decrease on `Session_End` too! I am glad I could help! :)

Comment: Please update your question with the new code so we can help you

Comment: @YourSolutionPartner ok, this should give you the way.